# Add OR operator to SO URL's so multiple categories can be browsed at once

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, sorting

I would like to see an operator implemented in the SO questions URL much like the `+` operator already is:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+html`

The reason I would like to request this feature is so that I may browse all/a combination of my tags at the same time for the newest asked questions, something like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css;html` or `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css~html`.

The current way to do this is to go to unanswered questions, then the My tags tab; sure this brings up all unanswered questions in my favorite tags but they are organized by votes which really doesn't help me answer people's questions (those with low votes). This is why I propose the above; it means that all my tags will be sorted by date posted and thus I can see them as they are asked rather than having to trawl through pages and pages of questions in order to find recent ones that have yet to be answered in my tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can already do that, using `+or+`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+or+html

Answer (score 5):

You can do this currently, though it's not the most obvious.

The search box at the top of the page defaults to using `and`.  So, putting in `[css] [html]` generates the following url:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+html`

The url can be modified to add in the or operator as such:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+or+html`

This can be extracted back to the search box so that you end up with the url you need.  If you put `[css] [or] [html]` into the search box, you'll end up with `or` included in the url as you want without having to modify the url manually.

Comment: And what would happen if a question had the `[or]` tag?

Comment: that tag is not allowed for that reason

Answer (score 0):

Use `[tag1] [or] [tag2]`. Easy.

Comment: Please don't just repeat other answers with no new information.