# Search for two tags (OR, not AND)

Tags: discussion, tags, search, tag-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)
>   [Add OR operator to SO URL's so multiple categories can be broswed at once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79181/add-or-operator-to-so-urls-so-multiple-categories-can-be-broswed-at-once)

I want to browse two tags simultaneously. That is to say, I want to see any question tagged with *either one* of the two tags.

I've tried `[tag1] OR [tag2]`, and `[tag1 OR tag2]`, to no avail.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: You can do this, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79181/add-or-operator-to-so-urls-so-multiple-categories-can-be-broswed-at-once/79183#79183

Comment: @martin: works great. Thanks. But why can't I do this from within the search box?

Comment: @martin - Awesome!  I had no idea

Comment: @Joseph, you _can_ do OR in search, not sure you really _should_ though, e.g. [tag1] [or] [tag2] [or] [tag3] evaluates to an OR of those three tags.

Comment: @martin: Haha. That's cheating. It wasn't designed for that. As far as the search box is concerned, you entered 5 tags in there. It just so happens that the way the URL gets structured is the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `/questions/tagged` URL syntax supports OR searching, for example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+java

searches for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [java](/questions/tagged/java)

[image: Or Tag Search]

Likewise the RSS `/feeds` URL:

- https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%23+or+java&sort=newest

<strike>I don't know of a syntax to enter this into the search box; you have to construct the URL by hand.</strike>

Thanks to @martinclayton the search syntax `[c#][or][java]` does the trick.

Comment: The [or] doesn't work for me, or it doesn't work anymore. Is there any other way to use OR in the search box?

Comment: Okay apparently this works but only if you're not using other search filters like is:question closed:no